# woocommerce_locate_template filter from plugin instead of theme

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I found this article on using plugins instead of themes to override a Woocommerce template: 
https://www.skyverge.com/blog/override-woocommerce-template-file-within-a-plugin/

It seems to almost work, but it's not working for any templates that are in the root of the woocommerce/templates directory (like single-product.php or content-single-product.php).

To illustrate, I have this filter:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_locate_template', array($this, 'woocommerce_locate_template'), 10, 3);
```

calling this function:

```
public function woocommerce_locate_template($template, $template_name, $template_path) { 
global $woocommerce; 
al_log('Looking for ' . $template . ', ' . $template_name . ', ' . $template_path); 
$_template = $template; 
if (! $template_path) $template_path = $woocommerce->template_url; 
$plugin_path = $this->my_plugin_path() .'/woocommerce/'; 
//look within passed path within the theme. This is the priority 
$template = locate_template( 
array( 
$template_path . $template_name, 
$template_name, 
) 
); 
//modification: get the template from this plugin, if it exists 
if (!$template && file_exists($plugin_path . $template_name)) 
$template = $plugin_path . $template_name; 

//use default template 
if (! $template) { 
$template = $_template; 
} 
return $template; 
}
```

It results in these log lines:

```
[davetbo@dev wp-content]$ [05-Feb-2016 17:10:46 UTC] Looking for /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/global/breadcrumb.php, global/breadcrumb.php, woocommerce/ 
[05-Feb-2016 17:10:47 UTC] Looking for /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/sale-flash.php, single-product/sale-flash.php, woocommerce/ 
[05-Feb-2016 17:10:47 UTC] Looking for /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-image.php, single-product/product-image.php, woocommerce/ 
[05-Feb-2016 17:10:47 UTC] Looking for /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-thumbnails.php, single-product/product-thumbnails.php, woocommerce/ 
[05-Feb-2016 17:10:47 UTC] Looking for /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/title.php, single-product/title.php, woocommerce/ 
[05-Feb-2016 17:10:47 UTC] Looking for /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/rating.php, single-product/rating.php, woocommerce/ 
[05-Feb-2016 17:10:47 UTC] Looking for /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/price.php, single-product/price.php, woocommerce/ 
[05-Feb-2016 17:10:47 UTC] Looking for /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/short-description.php, single-product/short-description.php, woocommerce/ 
[05-Feb-2016 17:10:47 UTC] Looking for /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/meta.php, single-product/meta.php, woocommerce/ 
[05-Feb-2016 17:10:47 UTC] Looking for /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/share.php, single-product/share.php, woocommerce/ 
[05-Feb-2016 17:10:47 UTC] Looking for /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/tabs/tabs.php, single-product/tabs/tabs.php, woocommerce/ 
[05-Feb-2016 17:10:47 UTC] Looking for /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/tabs/description.php, single-product/tabs/description.php, woocommerce/ 
[05-Feb-2016 17:10:47 UTC] Looking for /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/tabs/additional-information.php, single-product/tabs/additional-information.php, woocommerce/ 
[05-Feb-2016 17:10:47 UTC] Looking for /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-attributes.php, single-product/product-attributes.php, woocommerce/ 
[05-Feb-2016 17:10:47 UTC] Looking for /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/up-sells.php, single-product/up-sells.php, woocommerce/ 
[05-Feb-2016 17:10:47 UTC] Looking for /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/related.php, single-product/related.php, woocommerce/ 
[05-Feb-2016 17:10:47 UTC] Looking for /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/global/sidebar.php, global/sidebar.php, woocommerce/
```

As you can see, it never goes looking for anything in the root of the woocommerce/templates directory. Any thoughts as to why that filter doesn't work for single-product.php or content-single-product.php?

I currently have a woocommerce folder in the root of my plugin folder and inside that there's a single-product.php file with a die statement near the top, so I should immediately see if it's working. I did put the same single-product.php file in a woocommerce folder in my theme and it works there, but not from the plugin. Is there a different hook that I should be using? Please advise.

Comment: If you edit this `$plugin_path = $this->my_plugin_path() .'/woocommerce/'; 
` to this`$plugin_path = $this->my_plugin_path() .'/woocommerce/templates/'; does that break the other temlplates? If it does you could add an if statement to say "if you don't find it here, look there".
` Where it is logging `woocommerce/` at the end of the line it would log `woocommerce/templates/` and find the template, hopefully

Comment: What do you get if you `<?php echo $plugin_path; ?>` does it show the path you think you have the templates in - Looking at the documentation "your plugin / woocommerce / template name" doesn't seem to add the plugin location `function myplugin_plugin_path() {` may be missing or failing?

Comment: Steve, the way I did it above it logs every time it calls the hook.  I's not calling the hook for single-product.php or content-single-product.php.   Editing the code in that callback function is not going to help because the hook isn't being called. I submitted a ticket to WooCommerce and they said they don't support custom plugin development and they don't support using this from a plugin.  I suggested that it's a bug because the woocommerce_locate_template hook doesn't get called for anything directly in their woocommerce/templates directory, subfolder directories.  We'll see what they say.

Comment: It it any good using a child theme - can you put your edited pages into that or does that fail too? Anything you can do  in inc/template-loader.php or wp-settings.php? Looks as though the plugin is trying to hook into that and add another path for your templates folder. Does `$plugin_path` or `$template_path` echo anything at all though?

Comment: Where the plugin mentioned in your link states `if ( ! $template_path ) $template_path = $woocommerce->template_url;` do you get the default path back if you echo that `$template_path` from the plugin? Script seems to say "if you don't find the file in the plugins directory then look in the default folder" but never gets there.You might experiment with removing the `if( ! $template_path )` conditional so it will always take the path you specify.

Comment: It works in a child theme, but just not in a plugin.  I am building a site where users can change themes.  Therefore, I'd rather keep all my changes out of the themes if possible.   Every line in the log output above is found if I put it in my plugin.  However, note that nowhere in the log output does it say it's looking for any files that would come directly from woocommerce/templates (like content-single-product.php). It only lists things that are in a ***subfolder*** of woocommerce/templates. Since it never looks for it via that hook, you can't use those template files from your plugin.

Comment: What happens if you remove the conditional? - As far as I understand your script, if it already has a path it won't take a new one and will stay where it was. Looking at the plugin I would have thought it should look first into your plugin directory, then elsewhere if it doesn't find the template. Looks as thought there is a part of the if statement that should include that default path that is not working. Otherwise I have misunderstood the plugin script but going by their explanation of it that is what it should be doing. Sorry if I have wasted your time though.

Comment: What happens if you  `al_log(...` at the end of the function and include `$template` to your log to see where it is looking after the function just before `return $template;`?

Comment: This might help you analyse what is firing when http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224209/wordpress-how-do-i-get-all-the-registered-functions-for-the-content-filter Not sure if you can move where the plugin would fire using `$priority` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/