# Register form hook showing same field twice

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, registration

I have custommized registration form here but this hook is executing it twice.

```
add_action( 'register_form', array( &$this, 'customize_registration_form' ) );

public function customize_registration_form(){
        $first_name = ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) ? trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) : '';
        $last_name = ( ! empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) ? trim( $_POST['last_name'] ) : '';
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="first_name"><?php _e( 'First Name', $this->textdomain ) ?><br />
                <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_unslash( $first_name ) ); ?>" size="25" /></label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="last_name"><?php _e( 'Last Name', $this->textdomain ) ?><br />
                <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_unslash( $last_name ) ); ?>" size="25" /></label>
        </p>
        <?php
    }
```

I am getting same form area twice.How can i solve this issue?

Comment: It worked after writing same code in seperate class. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine, I'd suggest checking and making sure your class instantiates only once during runtime.

Try listing all callbacks on the `register_form` hook ([see this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224209/wordpress-how-do-i-get-all-the-registered-functions-for-the-content-filter) for the ways to do it). There is a chance your method gets hooked twice, thus duplicating the markup. If this is the case, consider using [Dependency Injection Container](http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html) to avoid this type of issues (and many others + other benefits).